# Is there any substitute method in laravel for before() and after() methods of kohana?

Tags: laravel-5.5, kohana-3

In **kohana** we use `before()` and `after()` methods which are called automatically before and after the called function.

Is there any substitute or equivalent method in **laravel** which perform these steps.

Comment: Maybe you could show us example what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Before & After Middlewares.

A middleware can run before or after a request is processed.

That depends on how the middleware `handle()` function is constructed, for example this is a before middleware, i.e. it runs before request is handled by the application (controller or route function):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Perform action
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And this one run after the request has been processed by the application (controller or Route function) but before the response:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        // Perform action
        return $response;
    }
}
```

You can register middlewares per route, per controller or global for the application.
You can find extensive documentation on middleware in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware)